Correctly getting system color for the borders
There is a WinAPI function GetSysColor(COLOR_ACTIVEBORDER) that's supposed to return this color, but on some systems the actual color of the borders is different from the standard (apparently, due to the Windows colors customization). However, GetSysColor() always returns the standard color, ie gray.
Any way to get the actual border color used by the system?
UPD a few variants that I've tried:
var color = SystemColors.Desktop; // correct
var color1 = SystemColors.ControlText; // incorrect; always black, no matter what Windows theme is active

var color = GetThemeSysColor(HTHEME.NULL, SystemColorIndex.COLOR_DESKTOP); // correct
var color1 = GetThemeSysColor(HTHEME.NULL, SystemColorIndex.COLOR_BTNTEXT); // incorrect

var theme = OpenThemeData(HWND.NULL, "BUTTON");
var color = GetThemeSysColor(theme, COLOR_BTNTEXT); // incorrect

var theme = OpenThemeData(_button.Handle, "BUTTON");
var color = GetThemeSysColor(theme, COLOR_BTNTEXT); // incorrect


Things are more complicated with theming, etc. Perhaps GetThemeColor() is what you are looking for?

System colors are exposed via the UISettings class. There doesn't appear to be a color constant for the border. It looks like a variation of the accent color.

You basically have to grovel the registry and calculate it yourself. Microsoft have chosen not to release an API for it for whatever reason (mostly antipathy towards developers, I think).

According to the Doc:GetSysColor function

COLOR_ACTIVEBORDER: Active window border. Windows 10 or greater: This
value is not supported.

You could try to use GetThemeSysColorBrush function with TMT_ACTIVEBORDER and TMT_INACTIVEBORDER.

This function gives the same i.e. wrong result for the border color.

If the theme data handle is not a NULL handle, GetThemeSysColorBrush returns the brush that matches the specified color from the SysMetrics section of the visual style. If the theme data handle is NULL, the function returns the brush matching the global system color.
Is the theme data handle NULL or not?

I call GetWindowTheme for the current window. However, it returns 0. I wonder if this is the correct result?

Anyway, this color is not correct for the system wide settings too.

If the return value is NULL, use non-visual-styles drawing functions. I suggest you could try to enable Visual Styles.

IsAppThemed does return true. Anyway, I've tried using OpenThemeData both for the window handle and with null to get global data, and it returns a non-zero handle, but it returns incorrect colors too. For instance COLOR_BTNTEXT always returns black, even when Windows theme is switched to dark and the real button text is white.

IsAppThemed will always return TRUE beginning with Windows 8. You need to enable Visual Styles.And I suggest you could also refer to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63159666/get-windows-10-theme-color-in-classic-c-winapi-win32-application

Hm. I've tried to use the WinRT API as another thread suggested and it returns correct accent/foreground/background colors, but for instance UIElementColor(UIElementType::ButtonFace) still gives the incorrect result. All the incorrect colors obtained from GetSysColor, too. Is there something else that the docs don't tell about?

What color is returned when you use GetSysColor with COLOR_WINDOW? More details you could refer to the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsyscolor#windows-1011-system-colors

Ah ok. This doc mentioned Aquatic Contrast theme so I tried this func with this theme and it returns 0x202020, that looks correct for this theme. However when I switch between non-accessibility themes, for instance Windows (light) and Windows (dark), the result always is 0xFFFFFF i.e. white.

I suggest you could refer to the Doc:Support Dark and Light themes in Win32 apps
Microsoft improves dark theme handling in newer versions of Windows 10 and Windows 11. If you want to get the color in the dark mode, you need to use UISettings to get all the settings of the UI including color.

Both Windows Dark and Aquatic Contrast are dark. I wonder why it works for one theme and doesn't for another?

According to the Doc:Support Dark and Light themes in Win32 apps
Some Windows development frameworks, such as Windows App SDK, support Dark mode natively and change certain UI elements without any additional code. Win32 apps often don't support Dark mode

However, what's the difference between these two dark themes?
